# Android: How to return huge byte array as activity's result?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, return, onactivityresult

```
private void returnImage(byte[] array)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(RETURNING_MESSAGE, array);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

I get that byte array by Camera via these callbacks

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            mCamera.release();
            returnImage(data);
        }
    });
}
```

At runtime I use the camera but the activity doesn't finish and Logcat says that `E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!`
Is it caused by the size of the image? I checked and found out that it's over 2 million bytes. I need to use my custom camera but I can't return my data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it caused by the size of the image?

Yes.

> I checked and found out that it's over 2 million bytes.

That is about twice as big as you can return.

> I need to use my custom camera but I can't return my data.

Either:

1. Do not make these be separate activities, but instead have them as separate fragments within one activity, so you do not have to worry about an `Intent` as being the limiting factor, or
2. Use something else, such as a (temporary!) reference from a static data member to the `byte[]`, that allows multiple activities within the same app to share data, or
3. If the activity calling `startActivityForResult()` is in a separate app, use a `ContentProvider` to stream the bytes back

Comment: I used the second way or I'll have to manage yet another fragment...  when you say temporary you mean to set it null right after it is processed?

Comment: another doubt... it's better to have a static member in the parent or child activity (the one with custom camera)?

Comment: @user3290180: "when you say temporary you mean to set it null right after it is processed?" -- yes, so you are less likely to leak the memory. "it's better to have a static member in the parent or child activity (the one with custom camera)?" -- I am not sure that it matters.